# Cannot find Module when running Node.js

Tags: node.js, cmd

This is my first time running node.js, and I have file located in C:\source, called index.js. I am not sure what am doing wrong here. I checked if node was installed with node -v and the version number appeared so that seems fine. Any input?

```
C:\source>node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:783
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\source\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:780:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

index.js has:

```
console.log('Hello World')
```

Comment: can you mention what is written inside of index.js ?

Comment: Yeah, add it to the question.

Comment: How is this related to tag [tag:cmd]?